# Does calling a constructor means creating an instance?

Tags: java

I know that when using:

```
A a = new A();
```

It assigns a space in the heap,and then calls the constructor,at last returns the reference.
But I am confused about that, if I call a constructor in another one, or when the child constructor calls it's parent's. Will this two ways create series of instances? Or one "new" for "one instance"?

Comment: it will create instance if it executes `new`, not in case of `this()` or `super()`

Comment: Directly or indirectly parent's constructor invocation is always performed to make sure none of the allocated space contain some undefined values.

Comment: ah...got it,the purpose.thanks.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `this` or `super` on the first line of a constructor, this calls another constructor to do some of the initialisation work.  It DOESN'T create a separate instance.

So, if class `A` extends class `B`, and the constructor of `A` calls `super()`, this means that the space in memory that has been set aside for the instance of `B` will have an extra load of initialisation done; but this is done in the SAME space as the rest of the constructor for `A`.  So if you write `A myObject = new A();`, the steps would be -

1. Assign space on the heap
2. Run the constructor for class B (the superclass)
3. Run the REST of the constructor for class A
4. Assign the reference to the created space to `myObject`.

Comment: Thank your for you response,as what you said,it seems that each time we "new an instance" for a class that we define,each Object instance was created,right?

Comment: If you are asking whether there is a one-to-one correspondence between a call to new, and a case of an object being created, the answer is yes.  (Except of course for String literals, autoboxing, and various serialisation tricks).

Comment: Autoboxing does not seem relevant to "new" keyword,does it?Do you mean that "new String()" does not call the constructor of object?

Comment: No, I mean that there are a couple of ways an object can get created without there being a call to `new` in the code.  `String hello = "Hello";` is one of them.  Autoboxing is another.  But in general, one call to `new` = one object created.

Comment: ah...I knew something about the mechanism of creating string literal between the "string constant pool" and the "heap",thanks for your answer.David.

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow this example from [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html):

```
Point originOne = new Point(23, 94);
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
Rectangle rectTwo = new Rectangle(50, 100);
```

> Each of these statements has three parts (discussed in detail below):
>
> - Declaration: The code set in bold are all variable declarations that
>     associate a variable name with an object type.
> - Instantiation: The new
>     keyword is a Java operator that creates the object.
> - Initialization:
>     The new operator is followed by a call to a constructor, which
>     initializes the new object.

Therefore, **`new`** is a keyword used to **create** an object and a **constructor** initializes a new object.

Comment: I like this response...

Comment: but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there are four way to "initialize" a class:

1. block `{}` (rarely used)
2. membre field initialization `private in i=0`
3. static block `static {}` (class init)
4. constructor `public MyClass(int i)`

or 4.1 default constructor

(the constructor is called before the other ones)

but under no circumstances the constructor implies a new instance. **New instance is done by `new` operator**. When you call a constructir from another constrcutor (or calling a super class constructor) you are simply "calling a method".

Accept my lack of formalism, it is only a short incomplete summary.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that 1. (called an _instance initializer block_) is never used? Also, only number 3. is used to initialize a class; all the others are used to initialize instances of a class. Finally, the comment _"the constructor is called before the other ones"_ makes no sense; certainly the static block is executed before any constructor or any instance initializer. Field initializers and instance initializer blocks are executed _during_ the execution of the constructor. See [the JLS, §12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: Ted, I can not give a lecture about the java constructors, I have set out a summary of the possible initializations. Regarding the "not sense", see point 5 of the link that you sent me. Then, after 12 years of java, You're the first guy I know who uses the "initializer block" ... it is not a criticism of course ...

Comment: I use the initialiser block.  Very rarely.  But I can't say never.  Do I get to be second?

Comment: Thanks your you two,and I remember that the static block is use the class member,not the instance.right?

Comment: Yes, edited according to comments.